# Regex - Multiple matches, colon and empty spaces

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to get some RegEx working but fail slightly at my specific use case.

Given the following string for example

```
Device-1: P0_Node0_Channel0_Dimm0 size: 32 GB speed: 2133 MHz type: DDR4
```

I want to extract informations from this string preferably like that:

```
Device-1: P0_Node0_Channel0_Dimm0
size: 32 GB
speed: 2133 MHz
type: DDR4
```

So I tried a bit around and tested some expressions

```
(.*?):\s
```

Does work to some regard. Catches the first parameter name properly but after that messes up with the spaces.

```
:\s(.*?)\s\w*?:!?
```

Although this catches the empty space in the third parameter value, it only gives me the first and the third value. Also no parameter names.

Someone has an idea how I could achieve the expected behaviour?

Note: I'm doing this in Excel VBA, not sure if all functions are supported there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
([^\s:]+):\s*(.*?)\s*(?=[^\s:]+:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d9lTmH/2)

**Details**

- `([^\s:]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the first occurrence of...

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces that are followed with...
  - `(?=[^\s:]+:|$)` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `:` or end of string

Comment: Amazing, thank you!
I just edited the answer to remove the space at the end of the second group match.
Answer accepted.
And I had to edit "may" with "use" because of the 6-char-limit.

Comment: @CuttingWide: Sorry, did you mean to edit to `([^\s:]+):\s*(.*?)\s*(?=[^\s:]+:|$)`? I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Autoit example:

```
#include <Array.au3>
Local $str = 'Device-1: P0_Node0_Channel0_Dimm0 size: 32 GB speed: 2133 MHz type: DDR4'
$r_A = StringRegExp($str, '([\w-]*\:)\s*(\w*\s|.*)', 3)
ConsoleWrite(_ArrayToString($r_A, @CR) & @crlf)
```